# Mongoid and validation option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using `:if` option with mongoid like the following:

**Model:**

```
field :categories, type: Array

belongs_to :personality

validates_presence_of :categories, :if => Proc.new{ self.personality.name == "Parking" }
```

**View:**

```
<%= f.collection_select :personality_id, @personalities, "id", "name" %>
... 
<!-- TODO (JavaScript): Following checkboxes would only appear when personality "Parking" is selected -->
<input type="checkbox" name="structure[categories][]" value="Top floor" />
...
<input type="checkbox" name="structure[categories][]" value="Ground floor" />
...
<input type="checkbox" name="structure[categories][]" value="Basement" />
...
```

**Controller:**

```
if @structure.update_attributes(params[:structure]) 
  flash[:success] = "Structure was successfully updated."
  redirect_to admin_structure_path
else
  render :action => "edit"
end
```

When I try to edit existing record, it ignores the validation if I change personality to Parking and there is no value in `categories` (checkboxes). After diagnosing, it appears to me that it is validating against saved (or old) value of `personality_id` instead of the newly updated one.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saving your instance, the validations will be run first. This is why when saving your instance for the second time, it runs the validation against the old `personality` relation.

Basically, inside the `Proc` in your `if` statement, you can access your instance as it is when the validation runs. This means that if you change the `personality` to something else before calling `@structure.update_attributes` in your controller, it will use the new value.

```
def update
  @structure.personality = Personality.find(params[:structure][:personality_id])
  if @structure.update_attributes(params[:structure]) 
    flash[:success] = "Structure was successfully updated."
    redirect_to admin_structure_path
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to understand where does `groupoid` comes from :)